# linux expect language - script not working for if statement

Tags: linux, expect

For the following script, the if block in expect language is not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -10
set prompt {$}

spawn  ssh 1.1.1.1
expect -re "$prompt"

send -- "echo 12\r"
expect { 
        "12" {send "echo hunky-dory\r"} 
        "bg" {send "echo 1\r"}
        "ih" {send "echo 2\r"}
        }
send -- "exit\r"
interact
```

The code will echo 12. However, it does not obey the if block and so does not echo hunky-dory after the echo 12, as has been clearly argued by my script.

Out put with `#!/usr/bin/expect -d`:

```
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = ./testexpect.exp  
set argc 0
set argv0 "./testexpect.exp"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file ./testexpect.exp
spawn ssh <hidden for security reasons>
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {3920}
send: sending "echo 12\r" to { exp4 }
expect: timed out
send: sending "exit\r" to { exp4 }
tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1
spawn id exp4 sent <echo 12\r\nexit\r\n>
echo 12
exit
```

My expect block is not even being recognized.

Comment: run your script with `expect -d` to see more debug info.

Comment: @pynexj I put a d after the shebang, my if block is not even being registered anywhere, it just echoes 12 and then proceeds to the exit. And I cannot use sexpect, because I am trying to configure networking devices.

Comment: @pynexj, yes, by if block I mean the expect {} block, as it functions as a kind of if block.

Comment: please post the output with `-d`.

Comment: I added it in the main post, please take a look (it won't allow copy and paste in these comments without breaking formatting).

Comment: you `send -- "echo 12\r"` too early. the ssh connection is not established yet. you better wait for the shell prompt to show up before sending any commands.

Comment: @pynexj How would I program that in? and my expect script successfully echoes 12, so how can the ssh connection not be established?

Comment: *"my expect script successfully echoes 12"* -- this is the most confusing part when using expect. :) it's `echo 12` that you saw, not the result (should be only `12`). the command (actually the *string*) was sent but it did not get a chance to be run.

Comment: @pynexj, apologies, maybe I was not clear. The `echo 12` functioned normally i.e. only a 12 was outputted, but the expect block was still not recognized. Also, I added in an expect -re for the prompt as you can now view in my edits within the main post, it still runs the same as before: echoes the 12 as 12, then exits the ssh session. I know for sure that the ssh connection was established and the echo was run, as I can ssh in manually and do a history, and view my echo 12's.

Comment: the `-d` output only shows the command `echo 12` and you can see the `expect {}` actually timed out (see the line `expect: timed out`).

Comment: expect is quite timing sensitive. the same script (not well written) may produce different outputs.

Comment: @pynexj I agree, it appears to have timed out out in the log output, but this is not the case as the command was run. Reread the edits in my comment just above your most recent reply.

Comment: "I cannot use sexpect, because I am trying to configure networking devices" -- actually i'm using sexpect to configure cisco/arista switches. :)

Comment: expect syntax is tricky. you better first take a look at some well written scripts to start.

Comment: I copied the formatting of the scripts from the internet, and very carefully checked. There is no indication from looking at my script that any problems will occur, but the expect block is not even being registered.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean by "not registered". according to the `-d` output, the `expect {}` block was executed but the result is "timeout".

Comment: `set prompt {$}; expect -re $prompt` would not work. the single char RE pattern `$` can match an empty string so it would complete immediately.

Comment: @pynexj Ok, but it'll remain broken regardless. I've got an idea. Can you run the above script in your local environment? and then run an expect script of your own that works within the same environment and then we can compare our scripts; we just need two virtual machines where one can ssh into the other. I would truly appreciate if you could do this for me. Take your time.

Comment: I know the timeout value `-1` means "inifinite", but I don't know if `-10` acts the same way. Why did you choose `-10`?

Comment: @glennjackman, just tried and `-timeout -10` is the same as `-timeout 0`. (e.g. `expect -c 'expect -timeout -10 foo'`)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
set timeout -10
```

expect treats that negative value like zero. There is literally no time assigned for the `expect` block to act, and you go directly to `send exit`

Use either -1 or some value greater than zero for the timeout value.